# Массив объектов полностью переписывается при изменении 1 объекта

Tags: java, массивы, объекты

Тот код, который написан у меня, слишком большой, поэтому я написал похожий, который передает суть проблемы.

У меня есть объект:

```
public class object {
    static int a;
    static int b;
    static int c;
    object(int A, int B, int C) {
        a = A;
        b = B;
        c = C;
    }
}
```

И я делаю так:

```
public class main {
    static object[] obj = new object[3];
    public static void main(String[] args){
        obj[0] = new object(1, 2, 3);
        obj[1] = new object(4, 5, 6);
        obj[2] = new object(7, 8, 9);
        System.out.println(obj[0].a + " " + obj[0].b + " " + obj[0].c);
    }
}
```

И результатом выходит то, что все объекты стали как `obj[2]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Уберите модификаторы `static` с полей `a`, `b`, `c` вашего класса `object`, и ваша проблема решится.

Чтобы понять, почему так происходит, разберитесь с модификатором `static` в Java.

Кратко - статические переменные принадлежат всему классу, а не конкретному экземпляру, загружаются они при создании класса, и при вызове из любого экземпляра, это поле поменяется и у всех других.

Вы создали три экземпляра класса, у которого ваши поля являются статическими. В итоге, вы обращались к ним через один из экземпляров, а значения менялись у всех. Это обращение равносильно такому: `Classname.fieldname`.